# Obtaining computation graph structure of a forward pass in pytorch

Tags: graph, pytorch, computation

Is there any way that we can **automatically** extract a computation graph that represents the **forward pass** in a series of pytorch computations? We would like the nodes in the graph to have access to the functions that make up the forward pass, so that we can call them individually. We would also like to have access to the values of intermediate outputs of each function.

This would be something different from the computation graph constructed by `autograd`, which generally only represents the *backward* pass. Its nodes only contain a reference to a `grad_fn`, which is the derivative of the forward function.

For instance, if we provide the following code:

```py
import torch

x = torch.randn(10)
M = torch.randn(10, 10)
h = torch.matmul(M, x)
h = torch.add(h, x)
h = torch.tanh(h)
y = torch.sum(h)
```

We would like to automatically extract a graph structure like

```
     y
     |
   [sum]
     |
   [tanh]
     |
   [add] 
  /     \
  | [matmul]     
  | /      \
  x         M
```

Where each bracketed node could be an object (call `Node`, for instance) that stores a reference to its corresponding function as an attribute, and stores the output of the function during the forward pass.

It would be great if anyone could point to any pytorch APIs that enables some kind of functionality like this!

Comment: You may want to look into [registering hooks](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nnft_tutorial.html#forward-and-backward-function-hooks). You can register a forward hook for any `nn.Module` and the hook itself has a reference to the class instance. These could potentially be used to construct a dictionary during a forward pass. The [torchsummary](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary/blob/master/torchsummary/torchsummary.py) tool is relatively simple and uses a similar approach to build a summary of the forward pass, perhaps it would help you to take a look at it?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'll definitely check out the features you just mentioned.